# MySQL: Getting average or sum from 200,000 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I would like to get the average or at least the sum of 200,000 rows from mySQL database. This is how I am querying the database but the amount is too large for me to query because I cannot afford to overload the server.

```
SELECT user_id, total_email FROM email_users
WHERE email_code = 1
LIMIT 200000

SELECT SUM(total_email), AVG(total_email) FROM email_users
WHERE user_id IN
(
01, 02,..., 200000-th user_id
)
```

My question is there a way to somehow combine the two queries into one so that I can get just the sum or average of 200,000 email_users which has email_code = 1.

EDIT: Thanks to all that have answered. I didn't realise the answer was so easy - nested select statement.

Comment: a limit clause without an order by clause doesn't make much sense.  What 200000 rows do you want?

Comment: @DanBracuk - I had to limit by 200k because there's tens of millions of data in there. I just wanted a small sample of data for analysis as I cannot afford querying the entire database because it's a live server.

Comment: So you just want a sum of a random 200K records?

Comment: I'm not sure if performance is an issue with the IN clause, but if so you might want to populate a temp table and then do a join

Comment: @JohnFx - Yes a random 200k from the database.

Comment: @hagensoft - Unfortunately, I have no access nor authority to alter or create a temp table within the database itself.

Comment: I believe it could be done without the temp table, just do a join to the same table you were going to use as your temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(total_email), AVG(total_email) 
from (SELECT eu.*
      FROM email_users eu
      WHERE eu.email_code = 1
      LIMIT 200000
     ) eu
```

Some notes.  First, using `limit` without an `order by` gives indeterminate results.  You could (in theory) run this query twice and get different results.  Second, this assumes that there is a field called `total_email` in `email_users`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this assuming you just want any 200K records from the DB where email_code=1

```
SELECT SUM(total_email), AVG(total_email) FROM email_users
WHERE user_id IN
(
  SELECT user_id 
  FROM email_users 
  WHERE email_code = 1 LIMIT 200000
)
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(total_email), AVG(total_email) FROM 
  (SELECT user_id , total_email
       FROM email_users 
       WHERE email_code = 1 LIMIT 200000)
```

Comment: You're missing the `FROM` clause in the subquery.

Comment: Your second query won't work, because `total_email` isn't returned by the subquery. I'm guessing you intended it to be like my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(total_email), AVG(total_email)
FROM (SELECT total_email
      FROM email_users
      WHERE email_code = 1
      LIMIT 200000) x
```